# Ampersand model not finding its url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ampersand.js

I'm playing with Ampersand JS models. When I'm trying to initialize a new one,

```
z.add(this.state)
m = z.get(this.state.name)
m.sync()
```

or add one to a collection,

```
m = new ZModel(this.state)
m.sync()
```

I get an error `A "url" property or function must be specified`

According to the spec:

*By default, url is constructed by sniffing for the model's urlRoot or the model's collection url, if present, then appending the idAttribute if the model has not yet been saved.*

This is exactly the behaviour that I want, since I have a restful API to sync with. `urlRoot` is set, `idAttribute` is set too.

```
export default Model.extend({

  idAttribute: 'name',

  urlRoot: 'http://localhost:50000/locator/zones/',

  props: {
    name: 'string',
    type: 'string',
  },

  fetch () {
    Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments)
  }
})
```

A collection is defined, but I didn't pass it to the model, because I can't figure out from documentation how to do it. But supposedly it's not necessary as long as I have `urlRoot` defined. What to do here? I guess I could pass the collection to the model, or define the url programmatically somehow?

**Update:**

If I do this:

```
m.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    console.log('Rerender now')
  }.bind(this),
  error: function() {
    console.log('Error during model add')
  }
})
```

I don't get the same problem anymore, but instead of getting a POST, I get 2 requests with OPTIONS and PUT. If I omit the empty object {} argument, behavior doesn't change. Even though the spec says this:

*book.save();
//=> triggers a `POST` via ampersand-sync with { "title": "The Rough Riders", "author": "Theodore Roosevelt" }*

*book.save({author: "Teddy"});
//=> triggers a `PUT` via ampersand-sync with { "title": "The Rough Riders", "author": "Teddy" }*

I guess the documentation omits a lot of details. What's the secret to getting this to work?

Comment: I guess this is a good question for Ampersand support

Comment: What is the state of your question? Still open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *rick-butler* and *aaronmccall* from Ampersand gitter chat for the answer:

By default, if the model's ID attribute is populated the save method will `PUT`. `POST` vs `PUT`/`PATCH` is determined by whether the model has an ID by default. The actual logic is from the `isNew()` function in `ampersand-state`. You can overload this function to determine your own logic, or manually pass your preferred method in options.

In cases where I don't have a distinctive ID, I like to add an attribute called `fetched` to the session of my derived `ampersand-model`. When I fetch/retrieve the model from the server I set this value. I use that for my `isNew` value, and I use it as the `waitFor` attribute for subviews.

```
var Model = require('ampersand-model');

module.exports = Model.extend({
  constructor: function(){
    options || (options = {});
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
    this.onSync = this.onSync.bind(this);
    this.on('sync', this.onSync);
  },
  isNew: function(){
    return this.fetched;
  },
  session:{
    fetched: ['boolean', true, false],
  },
  onSync: function (model, resp, options) {
    if (options.xhr.method == "GET") {
      this.fetched = true;
    }
  }
});
```